# What did I declare wrong here?

Tags: c++, variables, declaration

Im sure this is a simple question, but its had me stuck for hours.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char name = mark;
  int id = 0410448;

  cout << name << " " << id << endl;

  return0;
}
```

It is giving me an error like I've declared them wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error should be pretty explicit. Something like *error: '8' is not an octal digit*. Then you get confused, so you google how octal numbers work in C++.

Comment: And `return0` is not a thing.

Comment: What is `mark`? Is it a char array, string or some other variable? Also, `return0` should be `return 0`.

Comment: Be sure to fix your **include** and "using namespace std;".

Comment: I rolled back the last edit, and fixed the formatting *without* fixing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this piece of code you have 4 errors:

- **include** should be:

  `#include <iostream>`

  - Why? You have to specify which header file you have to use with a preprocessor directive. Although that probably happened because of the way SO formats posts...
- `char name = mark`should be `char* name = "mark";` or `char name[] = "mark";`

  - Why? A char can only hold 1 single character, so you need a collection of characters to store your complete string "mark", which has to be in double quotes to make it a string and not another variable's name.
- `int id = 0410448;` should be `int id = 410448;`

  - Why? If you start a number with a leading zero it means it is an octal (base8) number, and this numbers only go from 0 to 7, as opposed to decimal, which go from 0 to 9 or hexadecimal, which go from 0 to F.
- `return0` should be `return 0;`

  - Why? `return0` is a variable name, but you never specified a definition for it nor a value, what you essentially wanted there is to use the `return` *keyword* with a value of 0 to indicate the program ended successfully.

Answer (score 2):

```
char name = mark;
```

will not work. char can only take 1 character and it also needs to be in quotes.

What you need to do is something like this.

```
#include <string> //this goes at the top


std::string string_name = "this is a string";
```

EDIT: If you don't want to use  then you'll need either a character array

```
char name[];
```

or

```
char* name;
```

Will will fix your code

```
int main()
{
    char name[] = "mark";
    int id = 410448;
    std::cout << name << " " << id << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

One last thing, you can't use 0410448 since it'll try to treat it as octal. Remove the 0 from your int.

Comment: heh, i skipped out on the "int id" thinking there wouldn't be a problem with it. There was a problem on literally every line of code lol.